# Sort an array of arrays by elements contained in each array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, geometry

I need to traverse all connected components in a graph.
The paths of the graph are stored in arrays like this:

```
var paths = [
  [5,6],
  [1,2],
  [4,7,5,6],
  [6]
]
```

Here i see that `paths[2]=[4,7,5,6]` depends from `paths[0]=[5,6]` which in turn depends from `paths[3]=[6]`.

Now, i would need to recursively traverse all paths to check which one is contained in another and process the ones first that could help to solve the other, i.e. i need to check which arrays are contained in some of the other arrays:

example:

```
process [6]
process [5,6]
process [4,7,5,6]
process [1,2]
```

Due to the large amount of elements, i would prefer not to use recursion.
Is there a way to sort this list of arrays by the elements in one array contained in every other array, so that i can process them by iteration?

EDIT: 
I think this could be solved by assigning a weight to each path composed as follows:
sum of the nodes contained in each path multiplied by how many times this node is contained in other paths, then sort the paths by length ascending and weight descending - but this is just only my guess...

Comment: `Due to the large amount of elements, i would prefer not to use recursion.` If your concern is that a function will hit the max stack size, there are ways around that. It's sort of "roll your own TCO" but it could be quite effective [here is a good article](http://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/js-recursion.html). At any rate, am I correct in thinking that `[5, 6]` contains `[6]` because the latter is smaller? In essence, only larger arrays will contain smaller ones, it isn't the case that `[5, 6]` contains _part of_ `[4, 7, 5, 6]`, correct?

Comment: @Vld: I read just yesterday the article you mentioned, i must admit i'm still on the way to digest it... To the point: they could be also have equal length, sorting by length was my first attempt, sadly without success in some more complex graphs..

Comment: Won't pair wise comparison work in your case? It will take `O(n*n)` time if `n` are number of paths (assume path-length to be less than some max length `k`)

Comment: @deblocker yeah, it took me a while to process that article as well but I found the techniques interesting. somewhat annoyingly you do have to modify your algorithms to make use of them but it's better than blowing the stack. Anyway, a simple sort by length is not going to be too hard `arr.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length))` would sort out an array containing arrays by length [example](https://jsbin.com/wavajeh/edit?js,console). It's a single level only, but going many levels deep would be a matter of traversing everything and essentially sorting any array encountered.

Comment: @RishitSanmukhani: could you please elaborate? I'm not sure to understand if pair wise comparison could help me.

Comment: @Vld: BTW, there is another great gift if you are interested: [Fixed-point combinators in JavaScript: Memoizing recursive functions](http://matt.might.net/articles/implementation-of-recursive-fixed-point-y-combinator-in-javascript-for-memoization/)

Comment: @deblocker great, thanks! I'll have a look at it later :)

Comment: Is this still the horizontal rectangle distribution problem? It's turning out to be even more complicated than I thought. I hope you find a solution.

Comment: @m69: :-) yes, you are right. In fact, each path other than the "best one" can contain connected components, which turns out in a kind of recursive problem.

Answer (score 2):

I guess... if i have understood correctly, you are after dependency sorting. Then i believe a possible way of achieving this job is as follows. This is one way i could have come up with however there might be simpler solutions as well.

We have to form groups of consecutive items those depend on each other (such as `[6]`, `[5,6]` and `[4,7,5,6]`) and then we will sort them according to their dependencies. I guess sorting among separate groups is not necessary since their items are not correlated (i.e. `[1,2]` can come before or after the sorted group with `[6]`, `[5,6]` and `[4,7,5,6]`).

```js
var paths = [
             [5,6],
             [1,2],
             [4,7,5,6],
             [6]
            ],
      lut = paths.reduce((table,path,i) => (path.forEach(n => table[n] = table[n] ? table[n].concat([[i,path.length]])
                                                                                            .sort((a,b) => a[1]-b[1])
                                                                                  : [[i,path.length]]),
                                            table),{}),
   sorted = Object.keys(lut).sort((a,b) => lut[b].length - lut[a].length)
                            .reduce((si,k) => (lut[k].forEach(e => !si.includes(e[0]) && si.push(e[0])),si) ,[])
                            .map(idx => paths[idx]);
console.log(sorted);
```

Ok we first from a look up table like object (`lut`) and in this particular case it forms up like

```
{ '1': [ [ 1, 2 ] ],
  '2': [ [ 1, 2 ] ],
  '4': [ [ 2, 4 ] ],
  '5': [ [ 0, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ] ],
  '6': [ [ 3, 1 ], [ 0, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ] ],
  '7': [ [ 2, 4 ] ] 
}
```

So we now know that path 6 has the most dependent. `'6': [ [ 3, 1 ], [ 0, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ] ],` means at `paths[3]` it is alone; at `paths[0]` it has a single dependent and at `paths[2]` it has 3 dependents. So we have sorted according o the number of dependents (`.sort((a,b) => a[1]-b[1])`).
Once we have our table it's only getting them arranged to give us the desired index mapping. The `.reduce((si,k) => (lut[k].forEach(e => !si.includes(e[0]) && si.push(e[0])),si) ,[])` line is a little funny. What it does is for each path pushing it's indice into an array "if" it is not already in the array. So we start with the most dependent one (6) and we push 3, 0 and 2. So when the turn of 5 comes we will not push the same indices again.

Comment: Yes!. It seems to me you know the problem, is that true? It would be very useful for me if you could share some more knowledge about this argument. How do you came up with '7':4? This is the key point which i'm not able to realize, even with the help of your too advanced piece of code.

Comment: @deblocker After i posted this snippet yesterday i realized that there was some inabilities and was looking into correcting that. Later today i will try to post something more efficient.